# Bootstrap responsive menu does not work on my template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am designing this template on bootstrap 3. But I notice the responsive menu which is default in bootstrap does not work when I resize my browser to check.

I have also done many responsive template before but they are works fine, only this template does not work. I have tried to find out the error but can't fix it.

Can anyone help?

Template: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/138944745/bootstrap_lambda/index.html

Comment: Do you have the original theme? does the menu on the original theme? can you share it?

Comment: It seems , you must include jquery.min.js before bootstrap.js . I hope, it would fix the issue

Comment: include  jquery.min.js and bootstrap.js and it may resolve issue.

Comment: Using Chrome's inspector is very valuable, as mentioned in the answers you included Bootstraps js before jQuery. Bootstrap.js needs jQuery to operate therefore it needs to be included first. The inspector says this explicitly, it also says there's a syntax error in your page js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In footer you included bootstrap.min.js as first and jquery.min.js as second. You have to change the order

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change like this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice... Welcome@Forhad